# Hibernte EntityManager doesn't persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've read posts similar to this one but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is in my case, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have an entity object `Xyz`.

This is my DAO class:

```
@Repository
public class XyzDAO {
    @PersistenceContext(name = "MyEntityManager")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void create(Xyz xyz) {
        em.persist(xyz);
    }

    public void setEntityManager(final EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MyEntityManager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>.....Xyz</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="${hibernate.connection.url}" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="${hibernate.connection.username}" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

xyz-config.xml:

```
<beans .....>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="XyzDAO" class=".....XyzDAO"></bean>
</beans>
```

Reading Xyz from the DB works fine, but if I try to persist Xyz it runs without errors but nothing gets saved into DB, so my assumption is that a transaction isn't being created. If I do `em.getTransaction().begin()` it gives `Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead` error. If I do `em.flush()` it says there is not transaction. So I must be doing something wrong, but can't seem to figure out what exactly.

Comment: are you managing transaction on your own or through Spring, are you using annotations `@Transactional`, how you are creating/plugin your transaction manager with transaction

Comment: @ankur-singhal what am I missing from the above?

Answer (score 0):

- `EntityManager` is an object obtained from the Entity Manager Factory.
  You should inject the persistance unit **MyEntityManager** to an `EntityManagerFactory` object reference and use it to get an instance of the `EntityManager`.

  ```
   @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "MyEntityManager")
   private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

   .....

   @Transactional
   public void create(Xyz xyz) {
      EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
      entityManager.persist(xyz);
   }

   .....
  ```

Check [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/StartTransactionandCommit.htm) also.

Comment: I had the same issue and following post and below configuration helped me to solve persist and remove issue.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm not sure if it's a good idea to answer my own question, but basically RESOURCE_LOCAL for some reason didn't work, so I had to switch to JTA. So, persistence works now, and files look like this:

DAO:

```
public class XyzDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void create(Xyz xyz) {
        em.persist(xyz);
    }

    public void setEntityManager(final EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" .....>
  <persistence-unit name="MyEntityManager" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/datasource/VAP_XA</jta-data-source>
    <class>.....Xyz</class>
    .....
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

No changes to config.xml. Hope this helps anyone, and thanks for the answers.

Comment: Did you try with what I have proposed? Didn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue below configuration helped me solve persist and remove issue with entitymanager.

https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-spring-transactional

```
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
    tm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    tm.setDataSource(getHikariDataSource());
    return tm;
}
```

For remove add below line:

```
entityManager.remove(entityManager.contains(user) ? user : entityManager.merge(user));
```